# How to merge lists element-wise to a new flat list

Tags: python

I have 3 lists

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]
c = [6,7,8]
```

I want to merge those list to a new list element-wise but have not found a way to do so.
The only way I found is with `zip()` but then I get a tuple. But it should not be a tuple.

Desired output:

`new_list = [1,3,6,2,4,7,3,5,8]`

How can I achieve that?

With `list(zip(a,b,c))` I get `[(1,3,6),(2,4,7),(3,5,8)]`. I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = [6, 7, 8]

new_list = []
for n in range(len(a)):
    new_list.append(a[n])
    new_list.append(b[n])
    new_list.append(c[n])

print(new_list)
```

a more pythonic approach as @Pranav Hosangadi suggested:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = [6, 7, 8]

new_list = []
n = 0
for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c):
    new_list.append(x)
    new_list.append(y)
    new_list.append(z)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: forgot to clean up last try, thanks for the notice. answer edited

Comment: It would be more pythonic to do `for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)` and then append `x`, `y`, and `z` instead of indexing in to the lists using `n`.

Comment: it's a nicer approach, thanks for the information

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted

Comment: yw, i suggest using the cleaner approach by @Pranav, but i kept both to give you the freedom to choose